# Redirecting domain name to open an HTML page

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, redirect, local-network

I have a script that is being hosted on my Raspberry Pi over my local network.

I'm curious how I would go about being able to type in `inventory` in my web browser on my PC to be able to open up the HTML page that is generated by the script on my Raspberry Pi?

To elaborate, how would I have my browser to know at `//pi/users/home/script/some.html` when I type in `inventory` in the address bar?  (Do I set this in my router or in a config file on my PC)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the 'keyword' entry in a bookmark's properties.

You first create a bookmark of the webpage you want to link to.  Then open the properties for that specific bookmark and enter the keyword of 'inventory'.

This way, every time you type in 'inventory' in your browser address bar, you will go to that page.